# Calculating sum of values based on another attribute as filter in QGIS

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, fields-attributes, summarizing

I have shapefile data set (Road segments) my area of interest is to calculate the length of all road segments having a particular attribute, e.g.: sum of (length attribute) when Attribute1=something. How to do this in QGIS using python, graphical model or any suitable method?

Comment: Have you read the documentation on the [`sum()`](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/functions_list.html?highlight=sum#sum) expression? If so, what is left unclear?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is one suggestion. Functions are available from processing toolbox.

1. Run *Add Geometry attributes* which will add a field *length* to a new in- memory layer.
2. Run *Statistics by Category* on the in-memory layer with field *length* selected for stats and your category attribute chosen:
   [image]
   The output of this will be a table:

[image]